# Remove subview from another ViewController

Tags: ios, swift

I added a PageViewController to a normal view controller as a subview in `viewDidAppear()` of my HomeViewController like this:

```
if showTutorial == false {
        addChild(controller)
        controller.view.frame = view.frame
        view.addSubview(controller.view)
        controller.didMove(toParent: self)
}
```

It works, but I can't figure out **how to remove it again** - the PageViewController contains a button which navigates through its pages. Reaching a certain page, I want to remove the PageViewController from the HomeViewController again, by clicking the button inside of the PageViewController.

How can I do so?

Button inside of PageViewController:

```
@objc func buttonAction(sender: UIButton!) {
    if currentTutorialPage != 4 {
        currentTutorialPage += 1
        self.setViewControllers([self.viewControllerList[currentTutorialPage]], direction: .forward, animated: false, completion: nil)
        view.bringSubviewToFront(nextButton)
        view.bringSubviewToFront(prevButton)
    } else {
        tutorialSeen = true
        defaults.set(tutorialSeen, forKey: "tutorialSeen")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try

```
self.view.removeFromSuperview()
```

For completeness sake you can use this extension

```
@nonobjc extension UIViewController {
    func add(_ child: UIViewController, frame: CGRect? = nil) {
        addChild(child)
        if let frame = frame {
          child.view.frame = frame
        }
        view.addSubview(child.view)
        child.didMove(toParent: self)
    }
    func remove() {
        willMove(toParent: nil)
        view.removeFromSuperview()
        removeFromParent() 
    }
}
```

Then

```
@objc func buttonAction(sender: UIButton!) {
    if currentTutorialPage != 4 {
        currentTutorialPage += 1
        self.setViewControllers([self.viewControllerList[currentTutorialPage]], direction: .forward, animated: false, completion: nil)
        view.bringSubviewToFront(nextButton)
        view.bringSubviewToFront(prevButton)
    } else {
        tutorialSeen = true
        defaults.set(tutorialSeen, forKey: "tutorialSeen")
        self.remove()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Was wondering why I didn't find `removeFromSuperview()` - forgot to add `view`.

Answer (score 2):

To remove a child view controller (including its view), you should:

```
willMove(toParent: nil)
view.removeFromSuperview()
removeFromParent()
```

Answer (score 1):

you can remove
text/views/alerts/etc from superview using

```
removeFromSuperview()
```

example:

```
let loaderText = "text"

loaderText?.removeFromSuperview()
```

for views is just the same

```
let container: UIView = {
        let container = UIView(frame: CGRect.zero)
        container.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
        container.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return container
    }()
```

used like this

```
container.removeFromSuperview()
```